Export custom keyboard layout to another mac (running Sonoma)
I have created a custom keyboard layout for my Mac (using Ukelele) to make special characters I use heavily for coding more accessible. I recently got a new Mac and would like to transfer this keyboard layout to avoid having to recode it from scratch. Both Macs run Sonoma. I am struggling to do this, could you help?
